# ActiveMQ and ThreadPoolExecutor working together

Tags: java, multithreading, activemq-classic, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I need to fetch the data from activeMQ and then pass it to executors running in ThreadPoolExecutor.

The problem is, I don't have to fetch next data from queue, until I have at least one thread in the pool sitting idle, ready to take on this task.

I can just busy wait until activeCount< poolSize. But I would appreciate any solution with some asynchronous handling of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused. It sounds to me like you simply want to have a message handler execute() a task and then you don't have to worry about anything. The task will be queued if necessary by the TPE and executed once an executor becomes free to do work. There is no need to wait until a message is available, you just push it from the message queue to the executor queue.

Comment: @Gimby, you are right, but this is the requirement that I can't fetch the data from the persistent ActiveMQ until there is a ensured room for execution.

Comment: Is it because there must be no delay between the time a message is consumed and a task is executed? Its a little difficult to envision the reasoning behind this, and without a proper reasoning its hard to identify what could be possible solutions. I have a gut feeling it involves not using ThreadPoolExecutor as it is designed to queue.

Comment: No, This is because persistence of data needs to be ensured. At any time if any of the component crashes, then activeMQ keeps the list of unprocessed messages intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
final ThreadPoolExecutor executor=...
new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    while(true){
        if(executor.getActiveCount()<executor.getCorePoolSize())
            executor.execute(mq.get());
      }
}).start();
```

Comment: This is what I mentioned in the last line, This is a busy waiting approach, but I am looking for an approach where I don't continuously check for the executor pool availability.